# Intervention Image gallery has black shadow foreground

Tags: image, laravel-5, intervention

I intergrated Intervention Image in my Laravel 5.2 application.

I can upload and resize picture.

But if I display all pictures in a gallery and click on a picture, I get a blueimp-gallery with a deep black foreground. And I dont know why.

[image: Demo Picture]

This is the image from the gallery.

[image: Gallery Picture]

And this is the screenshot from the blueimp-gallery view.

Does anybody know this problem?

Comment: I think the problem comes from the blueimp-gallery..

Comment: Do you know any options to check where the issue is.
I tried out to check the style attributes, but I cant find something

Comment: First to be sure if the problem is with slider check an image after the resize taking the url of image and reload it in the browser

Comment: I replaced the blueimp HTML code, this solved the problem.